# Best way to initialize Java constants based on environment

Tags: java, oop

I would like to initialize a set of variables, which ideally would be final constants, based on my development environment.

That is, if my app is set to point to my development env, then var=x, but if my environment is set to production, then my var=y.

I am not a fan of a single constants class with globals which can easily be sufficient for this.  I like the concept of storing my constants in interfaces but am struggling with the best pattern where the variable value changes based on the environment.

Comment: This is what configuration files are for.

Comment: There's also `System.getEnv(String)`

Comment: @KennethK. - can you give an example of such a config file.  That is basically my question.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart - I need to be able to set the value dynamically.  How would I do so for an Env Var ?

Comment: Do you need to set it while the program is running?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart - Yes.

Comment: It's not a constant if it changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Factory pattern to achieve this. You can call as **EnvironmentFactory** and based upon environment, you can set the value. To correlate, I provide the example of Person, a person can be male and person can be female based upon the gender. It means sex is a variable which you want store based upon gender. There may be many suitable patterns, based upon your situation, I suggest for **Factory Pattern**.

Comment: Hi Voter, if you suggest me some points, I can improve on these areas.